# cyrillic search

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2005

I modified one of the apps I made for russian market. Everything seemed to be fine, there was an issue when you enter data into database but it was solved by by setting page encoding to utf-8. So inserting and retrieving works fine. I ran into problem I just have no idea how to tackle.
When I ran following query (simplified) in mssql query analyser (so no chance that it got messed up in the code), I get no results even thought there are a number of records matching:
(version of mysql is 2005)

```
SELECT *
FROM institutions
WHERE city LIKE '%Москва%'
ORDER BY address1
```

even if I modify it to be :

```
SELECT *
FROM institutions
WHERE city='Москва'
ORDER BY address1
```

or some other variation, it just isn't working. Question is why?

P.S. In case you can't see cyrillic letters after I submit this, it searches for Moscow as a city.

Anyone has solution or idea what to do?

Answer (score 31):

OK just found answer and it is lame :) a little. You need to add N in front of unicode string.

```
SELECT * FROM institutions WHERE city LIKE N'%Москва%' ORDER BY address1
```

I will leave this in case someone else get stuck with it.

Answer (score 6):

The N tells SQL Server that it is unicode not ascii